# Add nested collections with aggregation in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm new to mongoose, I'm confuse while create the query. Can you help me?

I have video collection like this:

```
{
    _id: 603dea86cef0aed372cd9ce6,
    category: [
        "603dea86cef0aed372cd9cd8", // array of category objectId
        "603dea86cef0aed372cd9cd9"
    ],
    hashtag: [
        "603dea86cef0aed372cd9cee" // array of hashtag objectId
    ],
    video_id: '6925666264463576320',
    share_id: 'greate_video',
    author: 603dea86cef0aed372cd9cd8, // ref to Author objectId
    cover: 'https://path.to/img.jpg',
    post_by: 60083f24edae03650406ad48, // ref to User objectId
    status: 1, // enum status [0, 1, 2]
    date: 2021-03-02T07:34:30.635Z
  }
```

I want to query to get data with structure like below. I mean, I will find by _id and get related data form other collections, more than that, I want the video list show with status 1, 2 (not 0) and sort by video _id: -1.

```
{
    _id: 603dea86cef0aed372cd9ce6,
    category: [
        {_id: "603dea86cef0aed372cd9cd8", category_name: Tech},
        {_id: "603dea86cef0aed372cd9cd9", category_name: Mobile},
    ],
    hashtag: [
        {_id: "603dea86cef0aed372cd9cee", hashtag_name: tech},
    ],
    video_id: '6925666264463576320',
    share_id: 'greate_video',
    author: {_id: "603dea86cef0aed372cd9cd8", author_name: Nani, avatar: 'https://path.to/avatar.jpg'},
    cover: 'https://path.to/img.jpg',
    post_by: {_id: "603dea86cef0aed372cd9cd8", user_name: Username, avatar: 'https://path.to/avatar.jpg'},
    status: 1,
    date: 2021-03-02T07:34:30.635Z
  }
```

How do I write the aggregation query? I tried with query like this but doesn't work, it show empty [] result.

```
const videoList = await Video.aggregate([
            {
                $lookup:
                {
                    from: 'Author',
                    localField: "author",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "author_info"
                }
            }
        ])
```

Thank you

Comment: it should work when both side `author` is objectId type, please check collection name, in `from` put exact name you have in database.

Comment: I got it, I changed to `authors` and it works. But how do I define the conditions: only show videos with status 1, 2 (not 0) and sort by video _id: -1. I also want to add skip, limit as well.

Comment: for status match use $ne: 0 in `$match` stage and and for skip use `$skip`, and for limit use `$limit`, just google it you will find documents, i thinks its very easy to understand.

Comment: I got it, thank you. I works as I want now.

Answer (score 1):

name of collection usually written in plural lowercase letters so I think you should change Author to authors

Comment: I got it, I changed to `authors` and it works. But how do I define the conditions: only show videos with status 1, 2 (not 0) and sort by video _id: -1. I also want to add skip, limit as well.